# The keyword "is" in the return type of TypeScript function

Tags: function, typescript

In VSCode's source file, there are some functions with a particular return type specification, like this:

```
export function isString(str: any): str is string {
  if (typeof (str) === _typeof.string || str instanceof String) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

So I wonder what is the purpose of "str is string" instead of just writing "boolean".

Can we use "str is string" and the like in any other circumstances?

Answer (score 13):

That is called [User-Defined Type Guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).

Regular type guards let you do this:

```
function fn(obj: string | number) {
    if (typeof obj === "string") {
        console.log(obj.length); // obj is string here
    } else {
        console.log(obj); // obj is number here
    }
}
```

So you can use `typeof` or `instanceof`, but what about interfaces like this:

```
interface Point2D {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}

interface Point3D extends Point2D {
    z: number;
}

function isPoint2D(obj: any): obj is Point2D {
    return obj && typeof obj.x === "number" && typeof obj.y === "number";
}

function isPoint3D(obj: any): obj is Point2D {
    return isPoint2D(obj) && typeof (obj as any).z === "number";
}

function fn(point: Point2D | Point3D) {
    if (isPoint2D(point)) {
        // point is Point2D
    } else {
        // point is Point3D
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Point2D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20x%3A%20number%3B%0A%20%20%20%20y%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20Point3D%20extends%20Point2D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20z%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20isPoint2D(obj%3A%20any)%3A%20obj%20is%20Point2D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20obj%20%26%26%20typeof%20obj.x%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22number%22%20%26%26%20typeof%20obj.y%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22number%22%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20isPoint3D(obj%3A%20any)%3A%20obj%20is%20Point2D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20isPoint2D(obj)%20%26%26%20typeof%20(obj%20as%20any).z%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22number%22%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20fn(point%3A%20Point2D%20%7C%20Point3D)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(isPoint2D(point))%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20point%20is%20Point2D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20point%20is%20Point3D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D))

Comment: is it a typo? `function isPoint3D(obj: any): obj is Point2D`.  shouldnt it be `obj is Point3D` instead ?